# Select elements of Dataframe given different indexes and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a pandas Dataframe with index and columns, and given a Series where the Serie's index is the dataframe's columns, and where the Serie's values are made of some elements of the dataframe's columns, we want to return a list or series of the Dataframe's values.

I tried iterating through the series, and find element by element, i.e.:

```
result = pd.Series()
for c, i in sr.items():
    result[c] = df.loc[i, c]
```

This isn't very fast, and it does not vectorize the problem.

Comment: Better provide a minimal reproducible example for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these inputs:

```
# df
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24

# sr
a    1
c    2
b    3
dtype: int64
```

You can use a 2D variation of an [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels):

```
a_i, idx = pd.factorize(sr)
a_c, col = pd.factorize(sr.index)

out = pd.Series(df.reindex(index=idx, columns=col).to_numpy()[a_i, a_c],
                index=sr.index)
```

Or a more convoluted approach with a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = (sr.reset_index()
         .merge(df.stack().rename('out'),
                left_on=[0, 'index'],
                right_index=True,
                how='left')
        .set_index('index')['out']
      )
```

Output:

```
a     5
c    12
b    16
dtype: int64
```

*Note that this approach differs from your loop in case of duplicates in the index of `sr`. If this is the case, first drop the duplicates in `sr` keeping the last (`sr = sr[~sr.index.duplicated(keep='last')].reindex(list(sr.index.unique()))`).*